# How to prevent two links show the same content with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting

I have this case:

- /css/ <-- a folder
- /css/something.css <-- a file

If the user accesses the folder (/css/), I want that Apache returns the file. If the user tries to access the file directly, (/css/something.css), I want that he be redirected to the folder.

How can I do this without getting a loop? I've read a lot but I couldn't figure it out applying two rules, it always returns a loop. Note: this is my first question on Stack Overflow. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Put these in your htaccess file in your document root:

```
# internal rewrite to serve the file
RewriteRule ^css/$ /css/something.css [L]

# check if the actual request was for the file, then redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /css/something.css
RewriteRule ^css/something.css$ /css/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hey @JonLin, thanks for reply. Sorry that I didn't accept your answer yet, I couldn't try it out! As soon as I try it, I come back here and accept it (and anyway, it seems you're right! :D thanks for explained it also). Thanks again!